# Can i set the contents of ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a data model that has a few nested lists and i would like to use ListViews to show them because i like having the details in the list.

eg data Model

```
public class EventModel
{
    public List<EndPointType> Targets { get; set; }
    public string EventTime { get; set; }
    public DataEvent EventMessage { get; set; }
}

public class EndPointType
{
    public int Type;
    public List<EndPoint> Displays {get; set;}
}

public class EndPoint
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayCode { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to keep a list of `EventModel` in one ListView I know how to do this with tags and sub items.

My question is when a selection is made of an `EventModel` from the list
is it possible a second ListView updates its Items to reflect the `List<EndPointType>` of the selected `EventModel`

TL;DR Can you set the entire contents of a ListView similar to using ListBox.Datasource?

Comment: You can use `SelectionChanged` event to put new data in the other ListView - whether it is inserting directly to itemssource or updating bound collection

Comment: @Uriel_SVK I know how to use the Selection Changed Event. This itemssource or bound collection is what i require assistance with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: for winforms...
Try something like this for `SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var eModel = (EventModel)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem;

    var targets = GetEndPointTypesFromList(eModel);
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    foreach(var target in targets)
    {
        listview.Items.Add(target.Type.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: my Listview does not have an ItemsSource

Comment: @Paperwaste oops, didnt notice winforms tag, solution was for wpf, edited